# React Router v6 Nested Protected Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm new to React here (coming from an Angular background), trying to create a simple React app that has 3 different kind of routes:

1. Authenticated - anyone who is logged in can access this route, i.e. Home
2. Authorized - anyone who is logged in with a certain set of permissions can access this route i.e. someone who has the permission 'UPDATE_TEXT' can access the '/text-editor' route whereas someone with the permission 'READ_TEXT' cannot
3. Open - anyone can access whether logged in or not

I'm using React Router v6 and essentially would like to have a route inside a protected route inside a different protected route, something like this:

**App.js**

```
...some other code
<Routes>
  <Route element={<AuthenticatedRoutes/>}>
    <Route element={<Home/>} path="/"/>
    <Route element={<AuthorizedRoutes allowedPermissions={['UPDATE_TEXT']}/>}>
      <Route element={<TextEditor/>} path="/text-editor"/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route element={<NoAccess/>} path='/no-access'/>
</Routes>
```

**AuthenticatedRoutes.js**:

```
const AuthenticatedRoutes = () => {
  const[userJwt, setUserJwt] = useState(null);
  const isSsoEnabled = true;

  useEffect(() => {
    const authFn = async () => {
      const authentication = await AuthService.checkAuthentication(userJwt);
      setUserJwt(authentication.appUser);

      if (authentication.isAuthenticated && isSsoEnabled) {
        return <Outlet/>;
      }
      else {
        AuthService.loginCallback(AUTH_API_PREFIX, APP_NAME, ENVIRONMENT);
      }
    };

    authFn();
  });
}
```

**AuthorizedRoutes.js**

```
const AuthorizedRoutes = ({allowedPermissions}) => {
  console.log('authorized');
  
  const hasAccess = ... some code to check users permissions

  return hasAccess ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/no-access"/>
}
```

My log statement inside of AuthorizedRoutes isn't being called, because `<Outlet/>` is being returned too late. I can't move the if statement out of the useEffect hook because then I end up in an infinite loop (because loginCallback is redirecting using `document.location.href` which seems to be reloading the app).

What am I missing? Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AuthenticatedRoutes` needs to return valid JSX, and this can't be done from the `useEffect` hook. Refactor `AuthenticatedRoutes` such that it conditionally renders null or the `Outlet` while the `useEffect` hook conditionally calls the login callback function.

Basic example:

```
const AuthenticatedRoutes = () => {
  const [authentication, setAuthentication] = useState();

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const authFn = async () => {
      const authentication = await AuthService.checkAuthentication(userJwt);

      if (!authentication?.isAuthenticated) {
        AuthService.loginCallback(AUTH_API_PREFIX, APP_NAME, ENVIRONMENT);
      }
    };

    authFn();
  });

  return authentication?.isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : null;
};
```